# If statement issues in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib

I am trying to use multiple `if` statements to check a certain condition and then to plot some data using `matplotlib` in `Python`. Firstly, I am doing `os.walk` on a directory to get the list of files and subsequently load them to finally plot and save the figures. Here is my code:

```
def velocity():
    plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{Iterations\/or\/Time}$')
    plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Residual\/history}$')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.yscale('log')

    if 'Ux_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_x, value_x, color = 'r', label = 'x-vel')
    elif 'Uy_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_y, value_y, color = 'b', label = 'y-vel')
    elif 'Uz_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_z, value_z, color = 'g', label = 'z-vel')

        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig(os.path.join(plotsDir, 'velocity'), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
        plt.close() 

    return (time_x, value_x, lf)
    return (time_y, value_y, lf)
    return (time_z, value_z, lf)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(logsDir, topdown=False):
    for lf in files:
        if 'Ux_0' in lf:
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data_x = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time_x, value_x = data_x[:,0], data_x[:,1]
            (time_x, value_x, lf) = velocity()
        if 'Uy_0' in lf:
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data_y = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time_y, value_y = data_y[:,0], data_y[:,1]
            (time_y, value_y, lf) = velocity()
        if 'Uz_0' in lf:
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data_z = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time_z, value_z = data_z[:,0], data_z[:,1]
            (time_z, value_z, lf) = velocity()
```

The `logDir` has only three files to begin with and they are `Ux_0`, `Uy_0` and `Uz_0`. Interestingly, after `os.walk` when I `print` `lf`, I get order of files as `Ux_0`, `Uz_0` and `Uy_0`. Now, the figure that is generated by the function `velocity()` has only data from `Ux_0` and `Uz_0` and not `Uy_0`. However, in my function if the order of `Uy_0` and `Uz_0` is reversed such that I have `Uz_0` immediately after `Ux_0` as shown below, I get all the three plots as desired.

```
if 'Ux_0' in lf:
    print "Entered"
    plt.plot(time_x, value_x, color = 'r', label = 'x-vel')
elif 'Uz_0' in lf:
    print "Entered"
    plt.plot(time_z, value_z, color = 'b', label = 'z-vel')
elif 'Uy_0' in lf:
    print "Entered"
    plt.plot(time_y, value_y, color = 'g', label = 'y-vel')

    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(plotsDir, 'velocity'), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
    plt.close() 

return (time_x, value_x, lf)
return (time_y, value_y, lf)
return (time_z, value_z, lf)
```

I am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Why does `velocity` return variables that it takes from the global scope, and doesn't alter in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Padraic is absolutely correct about your `return` statements not making sense, the actual cause of the problem is your indentation and placing of the `plt.savefig` command.

If you look at where you have your `plt.savefig` statement, it only executes when you reach the last `elif`, i.e. when it finds `Uz_0` in `lf`.  When `Uz_0` is the second item on the list, the plot gets saved only at that point, so the last dataset is plotted but not saved.

You should probably have a `save_velocity()` function that you run at the very end.

```
def velocity():
    #Rows omitted for succinctness' sake

    if 'Ux_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_x, value_x, color = 'r', label = 'x-vel')
    elif 'Uy_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_y, value_y, color = 'b', label = 'y-vel')
    elif 'Uz_0' in lf:
        print "Entered"
        plt.plot(time_z, value_z, color = 'g', label = 'z-vel')

    return (time_x, value_x, lf)  # Do Padraic's fixes here!
    return (time_y, value_y, lf)
    return (time_z, value_z, lf)

def save_velocity():
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(plotsDir, 'velocity'), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
    plt.close() 

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(logsDir, topdown=False):
    for lf in files:
        #Rows omitted for succinctness' sake
        if 'Uz_0' in lf:
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data_z = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time_z, value_z = data_z[:,0], data_z[:,1]
            (time_z, value_z, lf) = velocity()

save_velocity()
```

A bit of code clean-up:

```
def velocity(time, value, lf):
    plt.xlabel('$\mathrm{Iterations\/or\/Time}$')
    plt.title(r'$\mathrm{Residual\/history}$')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.yscale('log')

    if 'Ux_0' in lf:
        velocity_color = 'r'
        velocity_label = 'x-vel'
    elif 'Uy_0' in lf:
        velocity_color = 'b'
        velocity_label = 'y-vel'
    elif 'Uz_0' in lf:
        velocity_color = 'g'
        velocity_label = 'z-vel'

    print "Entered"
    plt.plot(time, value, color = velocity_color, label = velocity_label)

    return time, value, lf

def save_velocity():
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(plotsDir, 'velocity'), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
    plt.close() 

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(logsDir, topdown=False):
    for lf in files:
        if any((filename in lf) for filename in ('Ux_0', 'Uy_0', 'Uz_0')):
            logFile = os.path.join(path, lf)
            data = np.loadtxt(logFile)
            time, value = data[:,0], data[:,1]
            (time, value, lf) = velocity(time, value, lf) # Not sure why you return any value at all here, do you use these values later in some way?

save_velocity()
```

Comment: Thanks @zehnpaard. This logic works exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You only ever return the same value the rest are unreachable so if you are setting the values in your if based on thinking you are getting different values from your velocity function, you won't:

```
    return (time_x, value_x, lf)
    return (time_y, value_y, lf) # < unreachable
    return (time_z, value_z, lf) #  < unreachable
```

A function ends when it hits a return statement so as soon as you get to the first statement it ends.

You can return multiple elements:

```
return (time_x,time_y, time_z value_x, value_y, value_z, lf)
```

then  use slicing to assign `res = velocity(); a,b,c = res[2],res[3] ,res[4]` etc.. extracting and grouping whatever you want.

Comment: That's right. `return` should be used as the final output. If your trying to get all of the values, you should use `print` and then return a value that gets to what the point the velocity function is.

Comment: thanks @Padraic. Can you elaborate your explanation?

Comment: @Deepak, you only ever `(time_x, value_x, lf)`,  you cannot have multiple  return statements one on top of the other. You can return a tuple of all the elements and index the returned tuple to set the values you need.

Comment: @Padraic. Your comment about functions ending as soon as it sees return may not be the reason for getting only two plots. Because, I am calling the function three times, for each of the files that I read.

Comment: @Deepakm but you only ever return one set of values so no matter what there is something inherently wrong with your code, you  cannot have three return statements

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `return (time_x,time_y, time_z value_x, value_y, value_z, lf) ` - this does not work. Because, as the first `if` is true, it only gets the value of `time_x` and `value_x` and not the others and it fails.

Comment: two questions, why are you using all if's? and what do you expect the two returns underneath the first to do?